# Not able to customize output prompt during nbconvert to pdf

Tags: django-templates, jinja2, jupyter, jupyter-notebook, nbconvert

I have a Jupyter notebook, and I want to convert it to pdf. The default prompt is annoying with `In[XX]` and `Out[XX]`, so I'd like to change them. In a new `template.tplx` file I wrote

```
((* block input scoped *))
    ((( add_prompt_in(cell.source | highlight_code(strip_verbatim=True), cell, 'Code', 'incolor') )))
((* endblock input *))

% Name: draw_prompt
% Purpose: Renders an input prompt
((* macro add_prompt_in(text, cell, prompt, prompt_color) -*))
    ((*- if cell.execution_count is defined -*))
    ((*- set execution_count = "" ~ (cell.execution_count | replace(None, " ")) -*))
    ((*- else -*))
    ((*- set execution_count = " " -*))
    ((*- endif -*))
    ((*- set indention =  " " * (execution_count | length + 4 ) -*))
\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\}]
((( text | add_prompts(first='{[{\\color{' ~ prompt_color ~ '}' ~ prompt ~ '}]:} ', cont=indention) )))
\end{Verbatim}
((*- endmacro *))
```

which successfully changed the prompt of input contents to `Code:`
However, when I tried to modify the output prompt, it somehow failed. Below is my code

```
{% if execute_result != None %}
    ((* block execute_result scoped *))
        ((*- for type in output.data | filter_data_type -*))
            \texttt{\color{outcolor}Execute Result:}((( super() )))
        ((*- endfor -*))
    ((* endblock execute_result *))
{% elif stream != None %}
    ((* block stream scoped *))
        ((*- for type in output.text | filter_data_type -*))
            \texttt{\color{outcolor}Output:}((( super() )))
        ((*- endfor -*))
    ((* endblock stream *))
{% elif display_data != None %}
    ((* block display_data scoped *))
        ((*- for type in output.data | filter_data_type -*))
            \texttt{\color{outcolor}Figure:}((( super() )))
        ((*- endfor -*))
    ((* endblock display_data *))
{% end if %}
```

The `Execute Result:` and `Figure` were showed correctly. However, any `stdout` under `stream` was gone. They just disappeared in pdf files. It seemed something was wrong here. Any suggestions are appreciated!